# Where to transform Redux state for use in UI

Tags: reactjs, design-patterns, redux, react-redux

I have a list of "Events":

```
{
 id: 1,
 description: "Did something",
 date: <date>, 
 eventTypeId: 1
}
```

I fetch these Events in componentDidUpdate and then they are passed to my component as a prop form redux connect mapStateToProps - they come from a "selector" - getEvents.

I want to display them on react-big-calendar which wants them in this format -

```
Event {
  title: string,
  start: Date,
  end: Date,
  allDay?: boolean
  resource?: any,
}
```

Where do I transform them from my object to the react-big-calendar object?

It seems like this must occur in the component, so if I switch to another calendar libary, my redux code would remain unchanged.

Is there a standard pattern for doing this? Should I just do this directly in my render method?

```
render() {
 let bigCalEvents = this.props.events.map(e => <big cal event>);
 ....
}
```

Or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of transforming them in the component you should write a selector and transform these events in that selector. Anytime you want to later change to a different library, you would just need to change the logic in one selector and not go about changing it in every component

```
const mapStateToProps(state, props) {
    const events = getEvents(state, props);
    return {
       events
    }
}

...

const getEvents = (state, props) => { // this can be a reselect selector as well
      // transform logic here
      return events;
}
```

Comment: What throws me is say I have a deleteAction, the standard seems to be to return the original object on successful delete and I don't have that anymore so I am just deleting by id, and returning the id.

Comment: In such a case,you can modularise your selector so that you can transform a single event as well and use that while deleting

Answer (score 2):

Can not find this on React docs now, but from a performance point of view - it is better to keep `render` method as simple as possible and not overload it with additional logic. 
Consider you component will rerender due to other props change - each time it will recalculate `bigCalEvents`

That why it is better to pass data to a component in a format it expects the data.

I would recommend you to do this processing in `mapStateToProps` function. Also if you are using `reselect` library - you can memorize results to avoid rerenders.

Comment: this was a great answer - both answers were so similar I just had to pick one